How do I fix the Margin on a jenkylls blog?
The margins on the Github pages site is very rough and close, and I wondering how I fix it. I can't really figure out the templates so I'm going with one I built.
I tried to space out the markdown on individual posts but it didn't work and isn't really a permanent solution.
Here's the link to the Github Repository: https://github.com/CaptainSapphire/PH-s-Blog
